# ui-router does not transition to child state from abstract parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

After a successful login the my is supposed to transition from the `login` state to the `home` state. Prior to the `home`, or any other state in the app accessible AFTER logging in, I want a few `resolve` methods to fire, making sure privilege/access data is loaded before the controllers. To do this I've created an abstract parent state with the resolves, and made all states other than `login` child states.

When the `login` controller fires `$state.go('home')`, the `$stateChangeStart` event is triggered, however the app seems to dissapear in to the ether after that. The `$stateChangeSuccess` never fires and if I step through the code I simply exit the debugger after `$stateChangeStart`. The state hasn't changed (I'm still on the login page) and better yet no error messages. Thinking/hoping I have some simple configuration set up improperly.

**config.js**

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            parent: 'app',
            authenticate: true,
            data:{
                rule: function($rootScope){
                    return true;
                }
            }                    
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            reloadOnSearch: false,
            authenticate: false,
            params: {
                'passwordResetSuccess': ''
            }
        })
        .state('forgotPassword', {
            url: '/forgotPassword',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/login/forgotPassword.html',
            controller: 'ForgotPasswordController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            authenticate: false,
            params: {
                'username':''
            }
        })
        .state('app', {
            url:'',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view class="slide-animation"></div>',
            resolve:{
                privilege: ['privilegesService', function(privilegesService){
                    return privilegesService.getPrivileges().then(privilegesService.privilegesData)
                                                            .catch(privilegesService.getPrivilegesError);
                }],
                alarms: ['alarmsService', function(alarmsService){
                    return alarmsService.setAlarms();
                }],
                firmsData: ['chosenFirmService', function(chosenFirmService){
                    return chosenFirmService.getFirmsData();
                }],
                notifications: ['notificationsService', function(notificationsService){
                    return notificationsService.setupGlobalAccess();
                }],
                releaseNotes: ['releaseNotesService, $rootScope', function(releaseNotesService, $rootScope){
                    $rootScope.loadNotificationData();
                    releaseNotesService.setupGlobalAccess(); 
                    return;
                }],
                setIdle: ['Idle', function(Idle){
                    Idle.watch();
                    Idle.setIdle(15*60);
                    return;
                }] 
            }
        })
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            parent: 'app',
            authenticate: true,
            data:{
                rule: function($rootScope){
                    return true;
                }
            }                   
        })
```

**app.route.js**

```
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');

        //////////////////
        //Check for auth key if missing redirect to login
        /////////////////
        if(toState.authenticate){
            if(authService.authKeyExists()){
                var authorized = toState.data ? toState.data.rule ? toState.data.rule($rootScope) : true : true;
                if(authorized){
                    if(toState.url.indexOf("/add") > -1){
                        $rootScope.selectedFirmId = null;
                    } else {
                        $rootScope.selectedFirmId = $rootScope.cachedFirmId;
                    }
                    var navigateFromString = fromState && fromState.name ? "Navigated from " + fromState.name + " to " : "Started from ";
                    navigationService.addNavObject("activity", {
                        summary : "Page navigation",
                        activity : navigateFromString + toState.name,
                        page : $location.absUrl().replace("#/", ""),
                        level : "debug"
                    });
                } else {
                    $state.go('home');
                }
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('login');
            }   
        }
    });

    // Hack because ui-router doesn't save previous $state
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if(fromState.name){
            $state.lastKnownState = {};
            $state.lastKnownState.name = toState.name;
            $state.lastKnownState.params = toParams;
            $state.previousState = {};
            $state.previousState.name = fromState.name;
            $state.previousState.params = fromParams;
        }
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="slide-animation-container">
    <div ui-view id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
    {{scrollTo}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently due to the inclusion of `$rootScope` in the `releaseNotes` resolve. Removing this dependency allows the app to load.